# Can I undo Permission Changes?

Tags: permissions, auditing

I'm trying to recover from an issue where permissions were removed by accident, but I don't know what they were. Audit Log only shows me which PrincipalIds were removed, but not what permissions they had, and the Recycle Bin doesn't contain that info either.

Short of restoring a Backup, is there a way to find out what permissions were?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short of a restore I can't think of a way you could really roll that back. I'd suggest restoring the DB to a test environment then resetting the perms with something to compare to. If you don't have a test environment you could restore the db with a new name and attach it to a new web app in your production environment.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing, restoring the content db to a different one and looking at differences to recover the information.

Answer (score 1):

*(Sarcastic response with a serious undertone): Yep, look up your security policy documents to determine what roles to restore. :)*

(More useful response): Nope, when you break permission inheritance and apply level permissions to individual items below a parent, that information is not stored anywhere when deleted. Only option is to recover from a backup.