# Recover deleted users from SharePoint site

Tags: permissions

Is there way to recover/restore deleted user in SharePoint site?

**Scenario**: We have deleted users (say 100 user) form a custom permission group and now I want to roll back the action.

Any Suggestions?

Comment: Did you just remove them from the group, or delete them entirely?

Comment: Have remove users from specific group

Answer (score 1):

I think you can't roll back this action. You should grant permissions again. If you don't know who has which permissions, you can restore a back-up database to your test environment and find permissions.

Maybe [this link](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/25932/can-i-undo-permission-changes) can help you.

Good luck..

Answer (score 1):

Well, like @compengTR stated, I don't think it is possible to undo action in Sharepoint, as far as I'm aware.  So, as far as I know, you have two options.  You can either assign the users back into the group manually (which might take a while), or you can use a script, such as JSOM or C#, to assign users back.  I can probably quickly write a script to show how to assign one user to a group, and then you can complete it to your needs if you want to use it.  This script will be written in C#, but all scripting languages share the same basic "idea" on how to do this.

```
using (SPWeb myWeb = SPContext.Current.Site.AllWebs["YourSiteName"]) {
  SPGroup myGroup = myWeb.SiteGroups["GroupName"];
  SPUser userToAdd = myWeb.AllUsers["Name_Of_User"];
  myGroup.AddUser(userToAdd);
}
myWeb.dispose();
```

That's to just add one.  I don't what those users would have in common, so I don't know how to get each one and make sure they are right, but that would be how you could script it.